# How do I make HTML text become invisible using an if statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an age restriction for other people to use, but I want some HTML text to be invisible by this if statement.
**This is h3 text**
The HTML Text:

#### If you are reading this, you are over 18.

The JavaScript:

```
var user = prompt("Enter your age [NO LETTERS]: ");


if (user<18) {


document.write("<div style='font-family:Arial;font-size: 29px;''>Age restrictions have been enabled for this session.</div>");


alert("You are too young for this content, some restrictions might be activated.");
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to turn text invisible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Javascript to hide and show drop down menu and text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860350/using-javascript-to-hide-and-show-drop-down-menu-and-text-field)

Answer (score 2):

- Please do not use `document.write` as it's only used for testing, it actually [might reset the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).
- There are only two possible outcomes, either a user is older than 18 or less. Use `confirm()` instead to eliminate redundant input.
- If there's a lot of content that needs to be censored, hiding everything in JS is not a viable solution. A better way would be to only apply a specific class to body:

Javascript:

```
var message = "Are you older than 18?";
if(!confirm(message)) {
    document.body.classList.add("nsfw");
    // Inform the user that some content might be hidden.
}
```

Use CSS for design and layout and JS for logic. Assign class "sensitive" to all sensitive content:

HTML:

```
<body>
...
<span class="any-other-class">Hi</span>
<span class="sensitive any-other-class">If you are reading this, you are over 18.</span>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body.nsfw .sensitive {
    display: none!important;
}
```

This way, every element with class `sensitive` would be automatically hidden if the user is underage.

But wait! Maybe you want to store user's choice? Use Session Storage!

```
function agecheck() {
    var key = "nsfw-preference"
    var message = "Are you older than 18?";

    // Remove nsfw class if it exists
    document.body.classList.remove("nsfw");

    // No preference data.
    if(window.sessionStorage.getItem(key) === null) {

        // Ask the user:
        if(!confirm(message)) 
            window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, "true");
        else
            window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, "false");
    }

    // If the user is underage
    if(window.sessionStorage.getItem(key) == "true") {
        document.body.classList.add("nsfw");
        // Inform the user some content might be hidden. Avoid alerts()!
    }

    // User isn't underage
    else if(window.sessionStorage.getItem(key) == "false") {
        // Inform the user if needed.
    }
}
```

Call this function once when the DOM/page has loaded.

Comment: Sorry your code did not work for me. But, I have solved the problem. Thank you for your help though!